# How to disable local variable font bolding in Resharper

Tags: resharper

Resharper 2017 seems to cause my local variable names to be bold for absolutely no reason and I don't know how to turn off this very annoying and unwanted behavior.
can someone please assist. I attached a screen shot.

Thanks,
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to change font options in Visual Studio's Tools → Fonts & Colours. You're looking for ReSharper's mutable variable item.

Comment: Thank you very much @citizenmatt. That solved my issue. It must be a new addition to 2017 because I don't remember it in older version of R#.

Comment: It also depends if R#'s "Colour identifiers" option is enabled.